# Android custom checkbox for set custom font

Tags: android, checkbox

i created simple widget as custom checkBox as this below code, in this code setting custom font work fine but i can't check or uncheck `CheckBox`

```
public class CustomFontCheckBox extends AppCompatCheckBox {

    public CustomFontCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance(getContext()).loadFont("fonts/my_font.ttf"));
    }

    public CustomFontCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void internalInit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    }
}
```

xml layout:

```
<com.myapp.test.Widgets.CustomFontCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/sickness_depth_marginRight"
    android:button="@null"
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:text="@string/diabetes"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think you are messing with its constructor and its style use it like this

```
public class CustomFontCheckBox extends AppCompatCheckBox {


    public CustomFontCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomFontCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomFontCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        //set your typeface here.
//        setTypeface("");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes thats right, but i have more that 40 checkbox and i don't like to use this method